# Error en SED unix : "sed: -e expresión #1, carácter 14: orden `s' sin terminar"

Tags: regex, unix, sed, línea-de-comandos

Al ejecutar esta sentencia:

```
sed -e 's/á/\&#225;/g' ./fichero_entrada > ./fichero_destino
```

Me aparece este error:

> ```
> sed: -e expresión #1, carácter 14: orden `s' sin terminar
> ```

La sentencia está dentro de un fichero .sh que ejecuto por línea de comandos.

He probado en distintos tipos de shell: sh, Bash, sch... y el resultado es el mismo.

Comment: ¿Estás utilizando exactamente este código? A mí sí me funciona en GNU sed 4.2.2. El error aparece cuando tienes una secuencia `sed 's/busca/sustituye/'` y por algún motivo te dejaste alguna `/`. Por cierto,  usar Bash, sh, ksh o lo que sea aquí no es relevante, sino la versión de sed.

Comment: Gracias @fedorqui , voy a revisar la versión de SED. Creo que me está pillando el ";" como fin del comando. Aunque lo escape (\;) lo sigue cogiendo como el final.

Comment: Es la versión SED 4.2.1

Comment: No debería ser así. ¿Podrías pegar más código del que estás utilizando para tener más contexto? Algo así como `sed -e 's/á/hola;/g'` o `sed -e 's/á/hola/g'`, ¿te funciona?

Comment: Sin el ";" funciona. Con el ";" no.

Comment: Me parece curiosísimo. De todos modos, siempre puedes utilizar `\x3B` para representar el punto y coma: `sed -e 's/á/\&#225\x3B/g'`. ¿Funciona así?

Comment: Gracias @fedorqui. He probado con \x3B y mismo error :(

Comment: Sería interesante que pusieras el resto del script, pues tu error no es reproducible. Pon las partes relevantes así como valida qué da `cat -vet fichero` para ver si hay algún carácter raro por allí.

Comment: Me da el mismo error ejecutando el comando fuera del script, y también probando con otro fichero.

Comment: ¿Y también si dices `sed -e 's/á/\&#225;/g' <<< "holá"`?

Comment: Mismo error :(. En la posición del ";"

Comment: Pues me da a mí que es tu `sed` que está roto. Haz `which sed -a` para ver si tienes algún otro instalado, o bien reinstálalo.

Comment: Hecho. La solución ha sido codificar como comentaba @fedorqui el carácter á: 
"sed -e 's/\xE1/\&#225;/g' ./source_file > ./destiny_file"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando ejecutas una expresión de substitución en `sed` tiene este formato:

```
's/expresión regular/sustitución/[FLAGS]'
```

Sin embargo, si por algún motivo omites alguno de los bloques, es decir, si te dejas alguna barra, te salta el error:

> sed: -e expresión #1, carácter 14: orden `s' sin terminar

o, en inglés:

> sed: -e expression #1, char 14: unterminated `s' command

Veamos un ejemplo:

```
$ sed 's/hola/adiós/' <<< "hola amigüitos"
adiós amigüitos
$ sed 's/hola/adiós' <<< "hola amigüitos"
#                  ^---------------------------falta la /
sed: -e expression #1, char 13: unterminated `s' command
```

Por tanto, lo importante es darse cuenta de dónde se ha producido esta omisión.

---

En tu caso concreto parece que `sed` está interpretando, por algún motivo desconocido, que el comando no está completo, pese a sí estarlo. Probablemente se deba al uso de una tilde, en base a lo que [comentaste en la pregunta en Stack Overflow en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47351799/sed-unix-error-unterminated-s-command#comment81658263_47351799). Por tanto, puedes solucionarlo usando el carácter hexadecimal en lugar de `á` directamente:

```
sed -e 's/\xE1/\&#225;/g'
```

Y nótese que este es un buen truco para cuando debes modificar caracteres molestos, como las comillas. Comparemos por ejemplo cómo modificar la comilla simple de forma pedestre y usando el código hexadecimal (27):

```
$ sed 's/hola/ho'\''la/' <<< "hola"
ho'la
$ sed 's/hola/ho\x27la/' <<< "hola"
ho'la
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Perfectamente explicado!

Answer (score 1):

Prueba esto...
Pongo ejemplos de fichero para comprobarlo

**fichero_entrada:**

```
Esto es una prueba de acentos
á é í ó ú
```

Si lo ejecuto desde linea de comandos:

```
$ sed -e "s/á/\&#225;/g" fichero_entrada
Esto es una prueba de acentos
&#225; é í ó ú
```

Lo pongo y ejecuto desde un script también funciona.

Fichero script.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
sed -e "s/á/\&#225;/g" fichero_entrada > fichero_salida
```

Resultado obtenido (Correcto)

```
$cat fichero_salida
Esto es una prueba de acentos
&#225; é í ó ú
```

Comment: Todo esto lo hemos ido mencionando en los comentarios, parece que el autor de la pregunta tiene un `sed` roto.

Comment: Muchas gracias! El sed no estaba roto sino que era otra versión.

Answer (score 0):

Me he encontrado un problema similar y no tenía que ver con las tildes sino con la barra invertida. Entiendo que quieres cambiar:

```
á -> \&#225;
```

En mi caso yo quería cambiar:

```
$ -> \n$
```

Y obtenía el mismo error en algunas circunstancias (de hecho provisionando una máquina virtual de Vagrant), pero no en otras.

Lo que he visto es que la barra invertida funciona como carácter de escape en la expresión de manera que la tienes que doblar, es decir, escribir:

```
sed -e 's/á/\\&#225;/g' ./fichero_entrada > ./fichero_destino
```

Es posible que también necesites el resto con el tema de las tildes, no lo sé seguro.

En mi caso me funcionó:

```
sed -i -e 's/$ /\\n$ /g' /home/vagrant/.bashrc
```

Básicamente estaba haciendo que el prompt de la terminal lleve un salto de línea.